# subprocess.call to perl program not working with input file paths?

Tags: python, perl, subprocess

I need to call a perl script from python. I am using subprocess.call(). In command line the perl progam works fine. Also

```
cmd = [ 'C:/Perl/bin/perl', 'D:/pgm.pl', '-h' ]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This is giving a return code 0. I think this means it is working fine. But when I add the input paths and other arguments,i.e.

```
cmd = [ 'C:/Perl/bin/perl', 'D:/pgm.pl', '-m', 'mode', 'D:/input.txt', 'D:/out.xml' ]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

I am getting a return code of 22 and output is not obtained.(* It works in cmd).

please help. I am stuck with this and not able to proceed my work. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: what is `echo %errorlevel%` if you run it in cmd?

Comment: unrelated: you could use `r'D:\pgm.pl'` instead of `'D:/pgm.pl'`.

Comment: Still it is not working. Giving return code 22.

Comment: You said: "it works in cmd". What is the errorlevel  in cmd?

Comment: Tried  echo %errorlevel%- Returned Exit code 0

Comment: Are you sure the first command works? Add `.exe` extension to `perl`

Comment: Sir, even while simply using  'perl', the first command works. I tried with ' .exe' also , but still its not working.

Comment: Copy paste the exact command that works in cmd (pass it as is to `call()`)

Comment: Sir, I tried by setting the input and output paths to the working directory of python program. Now it works.  My python is now in D:/works/pgm.py and input is in D:/works/test/input.txt. But I did not understand the actual problem. Can  you please help me?.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It looks like your issue is not Python-related i.e., you use different commands (different paths) in cmd and in Python. If you have a new separate issue; [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
cmd = [ 'C:/Perl/bin/perl', 'D:/pgm.pl', '-m', 'mode', 'D:/input.txt', 'D:/out.xml' ]
subprocess.call(" ".join(cmd))
```

Comment: I think you have to put the optional parameter shell=True if cmd is passed a string. tested it using linux: `subprocess.call("cat /etc/passwd", shell=True)`.

Comment: @Lynch: you don't need it on Windows.